# Is JWT right for me?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I've done a fair amount of research on the *many* different ways to authenticate and authorize users who use my frontend application to access my REST API. I've built a system that uses OAuth2 and JWT and need a sanity check since I'm working on this alone.

For a bit of background, my frontend is built using Vue.js and my API is built using Django with Django Rest Framework. My team is already planning on concurrently developing the mobile and desktop versions of this app which both would require authentication and authorization as well.

To keep things brief, I'll omit the alternative solutions I have and just talk about the most controversial one.

Right now, OAuth2 (my authorization server) grants users a JWT token using ROPC when they provide their email and password to my frontend client. I should note that my API (my resource server) and authorization server live on the same machine.

My application allows users to essentially signup using different plans (for example a free plan and a paid plan). When a user signs up for a free plan, I need the frontend application to not only disable certain features and elements in the UI, but also I need the authorization server and or resource server to limit what that user is allowed to query based on their plan.

The idea is when a user signs up or logs in, my authorization server will get the associated user record from the database and create a valid JWT with a claim attached that states the user's plan and maybe some other non-personal information. Then once signed it sends it off to the user where the frontend can enable/disable parts of the UI... etc. Hence, if a user logs in on mobile, we can customize the UI based on the same claim sent by the JWT.

My issue is that I don't know if this is a good way to go about it. It seems that everyone I've asked in my circle is split on using JWT or not. Those apposed mostly raise security issues, but, when from what I understand, many of the JWT security pitfalls are well documented and can be avoided just using some commonsense as with any other session/token-based authentication. I'm starting to get analysis paralysis. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**CLASSIFICATION**

I would say this is really an API Authorization question, as opposed to an OAuth question:

- The role of the Authorization Server and tokens is really just to prove the user's identity
- Product specific logic comes after the user logs in and is generally best handled in your app

**MY PREFERENCES**

Here is how I would handle it:

- Save the plan type to your product data when the user signs up
- After login, look up the user from the access token
- Then look up the user's plan type from your product data
- Produce a Claims / Principal object in your API containing both
- Enforce business rules based on the plan type claim

I would aim for a Claims object something like this:

```
class ApiClaims {

  // The user id in the access token
  userId: string;

  // The email
  email: string;

  // The plan type
  planType: string;

  // Other claims from the token

  // Other claims from product data, eg user roles
}
```

**RESOURCES**

If interested in this approach, these blog posts of mine may be of interest:

- [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/)
- [API Authorization](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)

**JWT?**

You need some kind of API credential that is sent in HTTPS messages and is web and mobile friendly, so I would use JWTs. You could follow the same pattern with any API credential though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to protect of course, but JWT bearer tokens are an industry standard. Since you control both the client and the authorization server, you can implement it however you like.

I would look into changing Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to authorization code flow. It will enable you to use social authentication providers like Google or Facebook to sign in users (while still maintaining plan info in your own service). Chances are that people trust those companies more to keep their credentials safe than your company, and it allows you to benefit from any authentication features (MFA) those companies implement.

Also, if you want the clients to read the contents of the token, you should use OpenID Connect id_tokens, as those are guarenteed to be in JWT format.